# What about an .exe indicates to Windows that it's an Installer?

Tags: windows, installation, user-account-control

I use a small installer file to launch a licensing program and then launch our program.

but the small installer triggers User Account Control on Windows 7 and above (if UAC is set. (See screenshot).

I guess I could just rewrite it but just hoping that there's a simple solution.

[image]

Comment: The application needs to be rebuilt with a manifest that explicitly says you don't need elevation.

Comment: It's named setup.exe? Because if I remembered correctly, this name triggers UAC.

Comment: The detection logic is described here: [Installer detection technology](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835540(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_InstDet), as mentioned a correct manifest is the solution.